# Different ways to solve a number sequencing problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, dynamic-programming

Given a integer N greater than zero.

How many sequences of 1's and 2's are there such that sum of the numbers in the sequence = N ?

(not necessary that every sequence must contain both 1 and 2 )

example :

for N = 2 ; 11,2 => ans = 2 sequences of 1's and 2's

for N = 3 ; 111,12,21 => ans = 3 sequences of 1's and 2's

I approached in the following two ways :

1. Using recurrence relation (dynamic programming) : It is coming out to be same as Fibonacci relation with F(1) = 1 ( N=1 and we have only one possibility 11 )
   and F(2) = 2 ( N=2 and we have two possibility 11 and 2 )
2. Using domino tiling examples as described in the concrete mathematics book chapter : "Generating Function".

But I would like to know, is there any other way to solve this problem ?
With possible idea and references .

Comment: According to your description, for $N=3$ the answer should be $3$, since the sequence $111$ also counts.

Comment: yes for N=3 we have 3 possibilities. corrected !

Answer (score 2):

This is just a somewhat more compact notation when using generating functions. We can select either $1$ or $2$ and encode this as exponents in the expression
\begin{align*}
  x^1+x^2
  \end{align*}
Since we want strings built from the alphabet $\{1,2\}$ which sum up to $N$ we consider all expressions $(x^1+x^2)^j$ with $j\geq 0$ and extract the coefficient of terms $x^N$.

We use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^N]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^N$ of a series.

> We obtain this way
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^N]\frac{1}{1-(x+x^2)}&=[x^N]\sum_{j=0}^\infty(x+x^2)^j\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^N[x^{N-j}](1+x)^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^N[x^{N-j}]\sum_{l=0}^j\binom{j}{l}x^l\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^N\binom{j}{N-j}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we represent all strings built from the alphabet $\{1,2\}$ by a *[geometric power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $$[x^{p+q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^{-q}A(x)$$ We also respect that the coefficient is non-negative and restrict the upper limit of the series by $N$.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^{N-j}$. Note the convention $\binom{r}{k}=0$ if $r\in\mathbb{C}$ and $k$ a negative integer (see e.g. (5.1) p. 154 in *[Concrete Mathematics](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*).

Comment: Hasn't something a little strange happened in your final line? $\binom{j}{N-j}$ doesn't make much sense (to me, at least) if $j<N-j$.

Comment: @MartinKochanski: It's just a somewhat extended usage of the binomial coefficient. I've added a note at the end of comment(3). OPs example with $N=3$ gives $\binom{0}{3}+\binom{1}{2}+\binom{2}{1}+\binom{3}{0}=0+0+2+1=3$. Regards,

Comment: Thank you: I hadn't come across that before, and it certainly does make the notation more compact.

Comment: @MartinKochanski: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If $N$ is even, then each sequence is made of $\color\red{2n}$ ones and $\color\green{N/2-n}$ twos.

Hence the total number of sequences is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N/2}\frac{(\color\red{2n}+\color\green{N/2-n})!}{(\color\red{2n})!\times(\color\green{N/2-n})!}$$

---

If $N$ is even, then each sequence is made of $\color\red{2n+1}$ ones and $\color\green{N/2-n-1/2}$ twos.

Hence the total number of sequences is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N/2}\frac{(\color\red{2n+1}+\color\green{N/2-n-1/2})!}{(\color\red{2n+1})!\times(\color\green{N/2-n-1/2})!}$$